# "Empty" cells in attributes table - QGIS3 - QuickOSM

Tags: qgis-plugins, attribute-table, qgis-3, table, quickosm

Just why? (look at picture below) Why no data in attributes table? There should be infomation about map features. I check this area in QGIS on PC with Windows, and there is no problem with table... Also when I work on Mac with QGIS 2.18 it also work correct. I don't know how to fix it...I tried uninstall QGIS, plugins... I don't know what to do... Please help :)

I'm using QGIS 3.4.5-Madeira and macOS Mojave 10.14.3

[image: QuickOSM window]
[image: Empty cells]
[image: What I need]

Comment: Please provide enough information for us to help you.

Comment: What information do you need? :)

Answer (score 1):

Those fields are most likely blank because whoever created the features didn't fill in the optional fields. That's pretty common with OSM data. You can read more about how Open Street Map works [here](https://www.openstreetmap.org/about). If you have local knowledge about data that's missing from OSM, consider becoming an OSM contributor.

The other possibility is that the QuickOSM plugin is omitting values that exist in the source data. You can check on this possibility by comparing the downloaded data to the data on https://www.openstreetmap.org for the same feature. If it turns out that the QuickOSM plugin is making a mistake, submit a bug report on the [QuickOSM plugin bug report page](https://github.com/3liz/QuickOSM/issues).

Comment: It's strange, because I check this area in QGIS on PC with Windows, and there is no problem with table... Also when I work on Mac with QGIS 2.18 it also work correct. I don't know how to fix it... but thank for respons @csk :)

Comment: that's exactly the kind of information you should include in your original question.

Comment: Sorry, it's my first post here :)

Comment: With that additional information, I now suspect that this is a bug. Please make a bug report, otherwise the plugin developer won't know to fix it.